# Save user highlighting of text over multiple (sentence) objects

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, text, highlighting

Say I have a text, which looks something like this:

```
<span> Some sentence in which a fox jumps over some fence. </span>
<span> Another sentence in which a dog jumps over some fox. </span>
<span> Yet another one, I think you get the idea. </span>
```

Say a user now selects bits of the text which spans over two `<span>` items and then presses a button to highlight or bold the selection. To the user it would look like this:

> Some sentence in which a fox jumps over some fence. Another sentence
>   in which a dog **jumps over some fox. Yet another** one, I think you
>   get the idea.

I am wondering how I could save something like this. I create these spans by iterating through an array which spits out the sentences, but how would I remember that a highlights spans over two sentences and is **one single** highlight (I say this because I could of course somehow save that the end of Sentence 2 & the beginning of Sentence 3 are highlighted, but this would treat the highlights as separate)?

I am using React here by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the characters that the user highlighted, regardless of where these characters are allocated.

Here's an example on how to do it with plain javascript:

```js
function selected() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    return window.getSelection().toString()
  } else if (document.selection) {
    return document.selection.createRange().text
  }
}

function boldify (txt) {
  var ls = txt.split(' ')
  $.each($('span'), function (k, v) {
    var currentText = $(v).text()
    currentText = boldWord(ls, currentText)
    $(v).html(currentText)
  }); 
}

function boldWord (ls, text) {
  $.each(ls, function (k, v) {
    console.log('v', v)
    text = text.replace(v, '<b>' + v + '</b>')
  });
  return text
}

function saveHighlight (txt) {
  console.log('Save <' + txt + '>')
}
// this helper var will hold all the span
// the user interacts with (you can pass this to get the el instead
// of className
var interactedSpan = []
// I said plain js, so sorry about the jQuery, just to be faster
$('span').mouseup(function () {
   interactedSpan.push(this.className)
   var myText = selected()
    saveHighlight(myText)
    boldify(myText)
   console.log('interactedSpan:', interactedSpan)
});
$('span').mousedown(function () {
   interactedSpan.push(this.className)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="a"> Some sentence in which a fox jumps over some fence. </span>
<span class="b"> Another sentence in which a dog jumps over some fox. </span>
<span class="c"> Yet another one, I think you get the idea. </span>
```

*not sure why I was downvoted, anyway improved the answer a bit with the `interactedSpan` and now also added the bold version, he asked for save or bold*

Answer (score 0):

You can just have two separate bold markers so that you can have a valid HTML which is the obvious solution as you mentioned. The question is if you have any requirement that doesnt work well with this solution like having a border around each highlight?

```html
<span> Some sentence in which a fox jumps over some fence. </span>
<span> Another sentence in which a dog jumps <b>over some fox.</b> </span>
<span><b>Yet another</b> one, I think you get the idea. </span>
```

Or you can avoid the idea of keeping each sentence in a span which doesnt add any value. Instead keep the start and end markers across sentences in array and just join them and display as a single paragraph. The start and end markers need not be `<b>` but any marker you choose.

```js
const array = ["Some sentence in which a fox jumps over some fence.",
"Another sentence in which a dog jumps <b>over some fox.",
"Yet another one, </b>I think you get the idea."];

const p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = array.join('<br>');
document.body.append(p);
```